# Animate scroll in element with jquery while element size changing with css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find a nicer solution for the following situation:

I have a **parent** element with dynamic dimensions, positioning and hidden overflow, it contains a scrollable **child** inside it.
When the user scrolls down to end of the **child**, the **parent** is reducing height and the **child** follows the change with animated scrolling. In the other way (scrolling up), the **parent** expanding height and scrolling of **child** follows it.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiara/t45wfr8v/) that demonstrates what I've tried:

```js
$(".scroller").on("scroll", function() {
  var sh = this.scrollHeight;
  var oh = this.offsetHeight;

  $("span").html(this.scrollTop);

  if (sh - oh - this.scrollTop < 40 && !$(".element").hasClass("reduce")) {
    $(".element").removeClass("expand");
    $(".element").addClass("reduce");
  } else if (sh - oh - this.scrollTop < 40 &&
    $(".element").hasClass("reduce") && !$(".element").hasClass("calm")) {
    $(".element").one("animationstart webkitAnimationStart oAnimationStart MSAnimationStart", function() {
      $(".scroller").animate({
        scrollTop: sh - oh + 40
      }, 300, "linear");
      $(".element").addClass("calm");
    });
  } else if (sh - oh - this.scrollTop > 40 &&
    $(".element").hasClass("reduce") && $(".element").hasClass("calm")) {
    $(".element").removeClass("reduce");
    $(".element").addClass("expand");

    $(".element").one("animationstart webkitAnimationStart oAnimationStart MSAnimationStart", function() {
      $(".scroller").animate({
        scrollTop: sh - oh - 150
      }, 300, "linear");
      $(".element").removeClass("calm");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}

.element {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: calc(100% - 4em);
  height: calc(100% - 2em);
  transform: translate( -50%, calc(-50% + 1em));
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.reduce {
  animation: reduceSize 300ms 1 ease forwards;
}

.expand {
  animation: expandSize 300ms 1 linear forwards;
}

@keyframes reduceSize {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -50%, calc(-50% + 1em));
    height: calc(100% - 2em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
    height: calc(100% - 4em);
  }
}

@keyframes expandSize {
  0% {
    transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
    height: calc(100% - 4em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate( -50%, calc(-50% + 1em));
    height: calc(100% - 2em);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span></span>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="scroller">
      Mr. Worf, you do remember how to fire phasers? Could someone survive inside a transporter buffer for 75 years? Computer, belay that order. The look in your eyes, I recognize it. You used to have it for me. For an android with no feelings, he sure managed
      to evoke them in others. The game's not big enough unless it scares you a little. Did you come here for something in particular or just general Riker-bashing? My oath is between Captain Kargan and myself. Your only concern is with how you obey my
      orders. Or do you prefer the rank of prisoner to that of lieutenant? The Federation's gone; the Borg is everywhere! Some days you get the bear, and some days the bear gets you. Maybe if we felt any human loss as keenly as we feel one of those close
      to us, human history would be far less bloody. Travel time to the nearest starbase? The Enterprise computer system is controlled by three primary main processor cores, cross-linked with a redundant melacortz ramistat, fourteen kiloquad interface
      modules. Sure. You'd be surprised how far a hug goes with Geordi, or Worf. Worf, It's better than music. It's jazz. They were just sucked into space. I've had twelve years to think about it. And if I had it to do over again, I would have grabbed
      the phaser and pointed it at you instead of them. Mr. Worf, you sound like a man who's asking his friend if he can start dating his sister. I will obey your orders. I will serve this ship as First Officer. And in an attack against the Enterprise,
      I will die with this crew. But I will not break my oath of loyalty to Starfleet. We know you're dealing in stolen ore. But I wanna talk about the assassination attempt on Lieutenant Worf. In all trust, there is the possibility for betrayal. When
      has justice ever been as simple as a rule book? Wait a minute - you've been declared dead. You can't give orders around here. And blowing into maximum warp speed, you appeared for an instant to be in two places at once. Your shields were failing,
      sir. How long can two people talk about nothing? Your head is not an artifact! Well, I'll say this for him - he's sure of himself. Wouldn't that bring about chaos? When has justice ever been as simple as a rule book? We finished our first sensor
      sweep of the neutral zone. I'll alert the crew. What's a knock-out like you doing in a computer-generated gin joint like this? Mr. Crusher, ready a collision course with the Borg ship. Shields up! Rrrrred alert! Yesterday I did not know how to eat
      gagh. Ensign Babyface! Not if I weaken first. I'd like to think that I haven't changed those things, sir
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with it that its quite clunky when scrolling up and can be bugged by scrolling fast top and bottom. I'm looking for a smoother and more bulletproof way to handle this situation and i'm missing something.

PS: Although now it has fixed values on some places for scroll and size, it will use dynamic variables overall and work on different screen and element sizes, so there is no way to know the exact sizes before rendering.

Thank you for your time

**EDIT:** As Anthony pointed out, the code is not working everywhere, it works on the latest Firefox but not on older versions and not on Chrome (not tested on Safari). It should work on browsers that supporting the css provided.

Comment: the scrolling up/expanding doesn't even work in the code you provided...

Comment: also, you can easily run into issues when animation events with fixed durations (i.e. the animation must take 300ms to complete) are triggered by user input (i.e. scrolling)

Comment: @Anthony thank you, you are right, i only tested the code on firefox and it was working there altough its not working now on either firefox or  chrome(and possibly on some others), i think i lost on the loads of reviews in fiddle and deleted the working one, i will try to edit it later, and you are also right with the durations, im trying to find a better workaround for this too, the above code is more like a demonstration to know what i want to achieve, so im open for any other method

Comment: are you simply trying to shrink the child element until it becomes "centered" and appears to have the same "border width" all the way around it as a user scrolls? i'm kind of struggling to understand exactly what it is you want to do

Comment: @Anthony yes, first it should represent that the element is scrollable and continues on the bottom (normal/expanded state), and as it reaches the end it should represent that the end of content reached by having some space at the bottom of the element(shrinked state)

Comment: @Anthony altough the problem is not the shrinking itself, when it shrinks, its covering the content on the bottom of the element, so you need to scroll down, the shrinking and the scrolling should go together and the expanding the same in the opposite way

Comment: ok, i think i understand. i'll try to slap something together in a codepen. ohhhhhhh right, i guess, yeah, it'll obscure some of the text when you change its size. didn't even think of that

Comment: oh, man, actually i think i'm gon have to pass. this will take up far too much of time to code since. if you change the height of the child element as he user scrolls, of course `scrollHeight` and `scrollTop` will also change. forgot about that. sorry

Comment: @Anthony scrollHeight will not change since its coming from the child and the height only changes on the parent, the scrollTop is changing tough and thats what the animate try to follow scrolling. I understand thats a lot of time to work it out im already thank you your effort :)

Comment: oh is there a reason u r changing the height of the parent and not the child?

Comment: @Anthony yes, the reason exactly what you pointed out, if i would change the height of the scrollable element, the scrollHeight and offsetHeight would change too and i could not follow the shrink and expand with the scroll (whats needed in that case too cause the content would be covered anyway). If i change the parent height, it only changes what i see from the scrollable element, and i only need to adjust to scrollTop to follow the animation. Seemed like a good approach altough im still open to any other methods